# Understanding histogram_quantile based on rate in Prometheus

Tags: histogram, prometheus, percentile, rate

According to Prometheus documentation in order to have a 95th percentile using histogram metric I can use following query:

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m])) by (le))
```

Source: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#quantiles

Since each bucket of histogram is a counter we can calculate rate each of the buckets as:

> per-second average rate of increase of the time series in the range vector.

See: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate

So, for instance, if bucket value[t-5m] = 100 and bucket value[t] = 200 then bucket rate[t] = (200-100)/(10*60) = 0.167

And finally, the most confusing part is how can histogram_quantile function find 95th percentile for given metric knowing all the bucket rates?

Is there any code or algorithm I can take a look to better understand it?

Comment: you can refer to my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65418483/11685341)

Comment: `rate[t] = (200-100)/(10*60)` Why the 10 in 10*60, shouldn't it be 5?

Answer (score 43):

A solid example will explain `histogram_quantile` well.

Assumptions:

- **ONLY ONE** series for simplicity
- 10 buckets for metric `http_request_duration_seconds`.

> 10ms, 50ms, 100ms, 200ms, 300ms, 500ms, 1s, 2s, 3s, 5s

- `http_request_duration_seconds` is a metric type of `COUNTER`

| time | value | delta | rate (quantity of items) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t-10m | 50 | N/A | N/A |
| t-5m | 100 | 50 | 50 / (5*60) |
| t | 200 | 100 | 100 / (5*60) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

- We have at least two scrapes of the series covering 5 minutes for `rate()` to calculate the `quantity` for each bucket

> `rate_xxx(t) = (value_xxx[t]-value_xxx[t-5m]) / (5m*60)` is the `quantity of items` for `[t-5m, t]`

- We are looking at 2 samples(`value(t)` and `value(t-5m)`) here.
- `10000` http request durations (`items`) were recorded, that is,
  `10000 = rate_10ms(t) + rate_50ms(t) + rate_100ms(t) + ... + rate_5s(t)`.

| bucket(le) | 10ms | 50ms | 100ms | 200ms | 300ms | 500ms | 1s | 2s | 3s | 5s | +Inf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| range | ~10ms | 10~50ms | 50~100ms | 100~200ms | 200~300ms | 300~500ms | 500ms~1s | 1~2s | 2s~3s | 3~5s | 5s~ |
| rate_xxx(t) | 3000 | 3000 | 1500 | 1000 | 800 | 400 | 200 | 40 | 30 | 5 | 5 |

Bucket is the essence of histogram. We just need 10 numbers in `rate_xxx(t)` to do the quantile calculation

Let's take a close look at this expression (aggregation like `sum()` is omitted for simplicity)

> `histogram_quantile(0.95, rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m]))`

We are actually looking for the `95%th` item in `rate_xxx(t)` from `bucket=10ms` to `bucket=+Inf`. And `95%th` means `9500th` here since we got `10000` items in total (`10000 * 0.95`).
From the table above, there are `9300 = 3000+3000+1500+1000+800` items together before `bucket=500ms`.

So the `9500th` item is the `200th` item (`9500-9300`) in `bucket=500ms`(`range=300~500ms`) which got `400` items within

And Prometheus assumes that items in a bucket spread evenly in a linear pattern.
The metric value for the `200th` item in `bucket=500ms` is `400ms = 300+(500-300)*(200/400)`

That is, `95%` is `400ms`.

There are a few to bear in mind

- Metric should be `COUNTER` in nature for histogram metric type
- Series for quantile calculation should always get label `le` defined
- Items (Data) in a specific bucket spread evenly a linear pattern (e.g.: 300~500ms)

> Prometheus makes this assumption at least

- Quantile calculation requires buckets being sorted(defined) in some ascending/descending order (e.g.: 1ms < 5ms < 10ms < ...)
- Result of `histogram_quantile` is an approximation

P.S.:
The metric value is not always `accurate` due to the assumption of `Items (Data) in a specific bucket spread evenly a linear pattern`

Say, the max duration in reality (e.g.: from nginx access log) in `bucket=500ms`(`range=300~500ms`) is `310ms`, however, we will get `400ms` from `histogram_quantile` via above setup which is quite confusing sometimes.

The smaller bucket distance is, the more accurate `approximation` is.
So setup the bucket distances that fit your needs.

Comment: maybe you using a float number to represent `rate_xxx(t)` is more real, since the `rate` result is divided the time, such as 5 * 60

Answer (score 3):

I believe [this](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/promql/quantile.go) is the code for it in prometheus
The general idea is that you use the data in the buckets to extrapolate / approximate the quantiles
Elasticsearch also [does something similar](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/rollup-job-config.html) (yet different/much simpler) in their rollup capabilities

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65418483/11685341)

Actually the rate() function is just used to specify the time window, the denominator has no effect in the computation of the pecentile value.

Comment: As @ospider said below, the `rate()` also handles counter resets properly. `increase()` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `reset` because counters can be reset, `rate` automatically considers resets and give you the right count for each second. Just remember that always use rate before using counters.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a descriptive explanation over this topic in [Prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#errors-of-quantile-estimation). The link is for "Errors of quantile estimation" section, but I suggest to read entire page.

And it explains that quantiles calculated this way are not really meaningful, better to say they lie about real situation and can guide you to incorrect decisions.