# what's the math behind histogram_quantile(0.9, rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[10m])) in PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to figure out the calculation behind

```
histogram_quantile(0.9, rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[10m]))
```

Based on https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_quantile, the above expression calculates the 90th percentile of request durations over the last 10m.

As I understand, `http_request_duration_seconds_bucket` is an array of buckets with `le` and counts. `le` specifies the bucket boundaries.

What's the calculation behind `rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[10m])` then, does it calculate the increase of counts in each bucket per second?

Based on the expression, above, `histogram_quantile(0.9, rate(...))`, the `rate(...)` part is like a cumulative density distribution (CDF).

Do I understand correctly?

Comment: please refer to my anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69938239/1033401)

Answer (score 0):

> What's the calculation behind rate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket[10m]) then, does it calculate the increase of counts in each bucket per second?

As explained by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497684/6517750), `rate` applied on buckets here calculates a set of `rate of increment`s that happened on all the buckets in the span of the last 10 minutes. So, to answer your question, it is a `cumulative density distribution` on the rate of changes calculated in a given time frame.

The `histogram_quantile` function then uses this data to compute quantiles/percentiles.